# How to use filteredArrayUsingPredicate with NSDictionary?

Tags: ios, swift, search, nsdictionary, uisearchdisplaycontroller

Now I'm using

```
let array = (displayNames as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
```

where displayNames is

```
var displayNames[String]()
```

But I want to use it with:

```
var displayNames[String: UIImage]()
```

How can I use `.filteredArrayUsingPredicate` with displayNames string part in NSDictionary?

Comment: What do you want to filter? Make clear your task

Comment: He/She wants to filter the keys of the dictionary which are strings.

Comment: @StephenPaul exactly!

Comment: @OrkhanAlizade did you try my answer? Is it appropriate for your task?

Answer (score 0):

Get the keys from the dictionary using the allKeys property and perform the filter on that. Try that.

RE-EDIT: Try something like this 
    `let theOriginalDictionary = [String : UIImage]()
    let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "", argumentArray: nil)
    let otherDictionary = NSDictionary(dictionary: theOriginalDictionary)
    let arrayOfKeys = NSArray(array: otherDictionary.allKeys)
    let filteredArray = arrayOfKeys.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)`

Comment: I got an error: `Value of type '[String : UIImage]' has no member 'allKeys'`

Comment: Ah, of course. That's because the `allKeys` property is only part of the NSDictionary class. Maybe you could create an NSDictionary with the [String : UIImage] dictionary and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `Swift`, why don't you use built-in functions like `filter`?

```
var displayNames = [String: UIImage]()
let result = displayNames.filter {key,image in
    return true // here add your predicate to filter, true means returning all
}
```

Comment: OP, please try this solution out. Looks solid and less verbose.

Comment: @OrkhanAlizade did you try it? Is it appropriate for your task?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to filter the dictionary, while *keeping* the dictionary type after the filter. There's a few ways to do this, but maybe the easiest is to extend dictionary:

```
extension Dictionary {
  func filter(@noescape includeElement: (Key, Value) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> [Key:Value] {
    var result: [Key:Value] = [:]
    for (k,v) in self where try includeElement(k,v) {
      result[k] = v
    }
    return result
  }
}
```

Then, if you wanted to filter a dictionary based on the keys, you can do something like this:

```
let dict = ["a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3]

let filtered = dict.filter { (k,_) in k != "a" }

// ["b": 2, "c": 3]
```

Comment: Using `let filtered = rosters.filter { (k,_) in k == "\(searchController.searchBar.text)" }  print(filtered)` gives me nothing

Comment: Is there a problem with the filter condition? What does `"\(searchController.searchBar.text)"` look like, for instance? Is that key actually in the dictionary?

Comment: Also, what are you filtering by equality on a dictionary? The nature of a dictionary means there can be only one value per key. Surely `rosters["\(searchController.searchBar.text)"]` would do what you wanted?